# NGXS dispatch cancle http request from another menu

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

I have weird situation using NGXS for example I have 3 menus :

1. Menu sales > call  http get sales data > has unsubsribe function in ondestroy()
2. Menu customer > call http get customer data > has unsubsribe function in ondestroy()
3. Menu set default year => has dispatch() methode but no http request data

default year

```
       this.store.dispatch(new SetYear(
        {
            year:'2022'                
        }))   .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('success default year')
            },
            error => {
                console.log('error')

            }
        );
```

user.state.ts

```
     @Action(SetYear,{ cancelUncompleted: true })
     SetYear(ctx: StateContext<UserStateModel>, action: SetYear) {
        const state = ctx.getState();
        ctx.setState({
          ...state,
          users: [{
            ...state.users[0],
            ...action.payload
         }] 
       });
      }
```

First i go to sales menu, second go to customer menu, and last  go to set default year menu and I default year with dispatch(), but http get sales and http get customer is called again. why this is happen? what is solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution my problem. In sales and customer component in ngonInit() I read ngxs store and give value to variable and call http request

customer.component.ts : methode ngOnInit()

Before

```
 this.users$.subscribe(async(data) => {
         let idstore = data[0].idstore;
         this.getCustomers(idstore) // call http request
    })
```

After

```
   this.users$.pipe(
        take(1) //=> code solution pipe+take
      ).subscribe(async(data) => {
         let idstore = data[0].idstore;
         this.getCustomers(idstore) // call http request
    })
```

that is works perfectly